How to hide a whatsapp contact for calls and sms
I am using two Whatsapp accounts on a dual sim phone.  I really want to keep the contacts separately.  I managed to set one contact as Whatsapp only, so it's not visible from the contacts app.
I am trying to replicate this, whenever I create the contact from WhatsApp, its visible in the contacts app.  Yet the previous one is not.
How can I do it again?  There must be a method to do it.
This is the reverse of what I want
I am using Samsung Note 20 with Android 13.  I can see from answers to different questions on this site that there are other possible solutions for earlier versions of Androids.

As posted in the question, I managed to what I wanted the first time.  But the second and subsequent ones would appear in contacts (for calls and SMS).
I tried deleting them from contacts and adding them from WhatsApp, but no luck.
Eventually I used the Contacts Optimizer App.
I had already installed the pro version a few years ago.  It is great to find duplicates and delete/merge them.
Using the app, I noticed that the errant contacts appeared under the email account as well as under WhatsApp.  I deleted them from the email account.  They still stayed under WhatsApp, so all good.
Note, I am not associated with this app in any shape or form.
